# I deployed an app on Heroku and got this error Error on on Heroku CLI: Missing required flag: » -a, --app APP app to run command against

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment

I built an app on Heroku which shows successfully deployed . But, on running heroku logs --tail I have  the below error line:

Error: Missing required flag:
»     -a, --app APP  app to run command against

my app.py is a simple flask app:

```
app=Flask(__name__)
model=pickle.load(open('model3.pkl','rb'))
@app.route('/')
def Home():
    result=''
    return render_template('index.html',**locals())

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    High=float(request.form['highValue'])
    Low=float(request.form['lowValue'])
    Close=float(request.form['closeValue'])
    result= model.predict([[Close, Low,High]])[0]
    return render_template('index.html',**locals())

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(port=3000,debug=True)
```

And my procfile has this :

web:gunicorn app:app

This is my first deployment on heroku and was even delightd to get to this stage after days of watching youtube videos on heroku deployment

I realy need an help on this .I am completely new and dont know what to do next

When i run heroku logs it returns the message below

ytes= protocol=https
2023-05-07T10:23:31.480761+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=easy-stock.herokuapp.com request_id=5d78bc5b-4635-47f7-b90a-8c55000f0e27 fwd="102.89.43.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-05-07T10:30:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user isiaqraheem43@gmail.com
2023-05-07T10:31:22.515886+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user isiaqraheem43@gmail.com
2023-05-07T10:31:22.515886+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3808dc98 by user isiaqraheem43@gmail.com
2023-05-07T10:31:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-05-07T10:35:11.706497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=easy-stock.herokuapp.com request_id=96e548b8-593b-4b36-ad6d-78a9034d6864 fwd="102.89.43.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-05-07T10:35:12.011959+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=easy-stock.herokuapp.com request_id=3ed4b58a-a138-414e-90cf-bed1c8124c75 fwd="102.89.43.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https